# Node-Red sending the file in http-request node is not working

Tags: node.js, node-red

I am trying to send the file with the http-request node but it is not working.

Please find the following image of Node-red flow.
[image]

In the **Request Body** node I have added the following code.

```
const inputFile = msg.payload;

const dataJson = 
{
    'name': 'testName',
    'description':'testdescription',
    'inputfile': inputFile
};
msg.payload = dataJson;
msg.url = 'myAPIurl';

msg.headers = {
    'authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN Here',
    'cookie': 'Cookie here',
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data;'
};

return msg;
```

This is giving bad request error.

In the `Read File` node I tried choosing both options `A single UTF8-String` and `a single Buffer Object` still I got the same error

---

But I tried to call the API inside function node using the request module. It is giving the proper response.

```
const request = global.get("request");
const fs = global.get("fs");

const url = 'API';

const tkn = 'TOken Here';
const cookie = 'cookie here';

const fl = fs.createReadStream('/tmp/node-red/app/data/filename.txt');
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': tkn,
        'Cookie': cookie,
    },
    formData: {
        "name": "test121",
        "description": "",
        inputfile: fl
    }
};

request(options, function (err, resp, body) {

    console.log(body);

});

return msg;
```

I am not sure where I am making the mistake if I use `http-request` node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sidebar docs for the http-request node:

> **File Upload**
>
> To perform a file upload, `msg.headers["content-type"]` should be set
> to `multipart/form-data` and the `msg.payload` passed to the node must
> be an object with the following structure:
>
> ```
> {
>     "KEY": {
>         "value": FILE_CONTENTS,
>         "options": {
>             "filename": "FILENAME"
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The values of KEY, FILE_CONTENTS and FILENAME should be set to the
> appropriate values.

Following this doc, your `msg.payload` is wrong, it should look something like:

```
msg.payload: {
  "name": "testName",
  "description": "description",
  "inputfile": {
    "value": inputfile,
    "options": {
      "filename": "filename.txt"
    }
  }
}
```